# How to use regexp for validate in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I want to use regexp in validation in nestjs.

For example:

RegExp

```
pagePattern    = '[a-z0-9\-]+';
```

Method

```
  @Get('/:article')
  getIndex(
   @Param('article')
  ) {

  }
```

What can I use?
ValidationPipe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would create a DTO class like

```js
class ArticleParamDTO {
  @Matches('[a-z0-9\-]+') // comes from class-validator
  article: string;
}
```

And then you can use it in the route handler like

```js
@Get(':article')
getIndex(@Param() { article }: ArticleParamDto) {

}
```

And then as long as you use the `ValidationPipe` it will all work. Anything that doesn't match will cause a 400 BadRequest

Comment: are there any ways to customize error messages for this case?

Comment: I believe the API for `@Matches()` is `@Matches(regex, message)`. Might be `@Matches(regex, options)` where `options.message` is the path you can use. Double check with class-validator's documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
@Matches(new RegExp('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*).+$'), {
    message: 'qwe',
  })
```

Comment: Please give context, what does it do?

Comment: I am not have "You must have 50 reputation to comment". I answered the question "are there any ways to customize error messages for this case?"